# .htaccess hiding string from URL 301 Redirects (including special character?)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My sites are have just been redirected to HTTPS from HTTP using htaccess. Since the sites show index.php? in the URL structure. I am unsure why its doing this.

Originally it was showing the following:
[https://www.example.com.au/index.php?/rest-of-URL](http://example.com)

Using the following code in htaccess I was able to limit it down to: [https://www.example.com.au/?/rest-of-URL](http://example.com)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php\?/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php? / [R=301,NE,L]
```

I need to remove the **?/** from the URL using htaccess

Please someone help :(

Comment: its in your condition, so simply remove it

Comment: Try adding an extra **?** at the end of the rewrite target, **/?**

Comment: so remove this ^GET.*index\.php\?/

Comment: where do I add the ? sorry

Comment: Adding another ? had no effect RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php?? / [R=301,NE,L]

Comment: Add ? at the end of the string, after the **/**,

Comment: RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php? /? [R=301,NE,L] **This did not work**

Comment: What url did you try?

Comment: same structure as above in the question

Comment: can you clear your browser cache?

Comment: Using Private browsing - this code **RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php? /? [R=301,NE,L]** redirects to the home page

Comment: Using Private browsing - this code RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php? / [R=301,NE,L] redirects to the right page with the Url structure of https://www.example.com.au/?/rest-of-URL

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by changing internal links for all pages instead. Thank you for everyone's help. If you have a solution that actually fixes it via the htaccess file I would be extremely interested. Thanks